# Why can't I do ls -a 1>&-?

Tags: io-redirection, io, file-descriptors

Why can't we just close `stdout` for a process?

I was trying out redirection commands. The following works:

```
ls -a 0>&-
ls -a 2>&-
```

which means close `stdin` and `stderr` for the process `ls -a`. But why does closing `stdout` fail? I am getting

```
aniket@aniket-Compaq-610:~/Downloads$ ls -a 1>&-
ls: write error: Bad file descriptor
```

I know it does not make sense to close stdout here but I am wondering why it is not allowed?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Obviously closing stdout does not fail, on the contrary, it succeeds because writing on it fails, as can be seen from the error message. Edit: to clarify my answer, what happens is that you first tell the shell to close the file descriptor, then the `ls` program tries to write to it. This is where the error message comes from.

Comment: That makes sense. I did not look at it that way. Thanks!

Comment: As a general rule, this is why the file-descriptor closing, although in some ways neater than redirection to `/dev/null`, can often be a problem, especially for programs that expect to be able to write output. Some programs just don't read/write on specific file descriptors, but more careful programs will report reading/writing errors on stderr, like any other error, and will exit with an error status accordingly, even if otherwise successful.